# Python launch a .xlsm file then handle window that is queued from the macro, but gets stuck

Tags: python, vba

I'm trying to run a Python script that begins by opening an excel.xlsm file. This file automatically queues up a macro at opening.  The macro is a login.  I used the pyautogui module to login to the window.

The problem is the login in part of the script does not work when executed together with opening the .xlsm file.  I believe it's getting stuck at the login screen.

```
import pyautogui
import os
import win32com.client

# open the xlsm file
if os.path.exists("macrofile.xlsm"):
    xl=win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename="file:///C:/Users/.../macrofile.xlsm", ReadOnly=1)
   #xl.Application.Run("IMS2_CDT_20170427.xlsm")
    xl.Application.Quit() # Comment this out if your excel script closes
    del xl

# move the mouse
# to the user name box
pyautogui.click(468, 342); pyautogui.typewrite("username")

# to the password box
pyautogui.click(466, 383); pyautogui.typewrite("password")

# click ok
pyautogui.click(576, 425)
```

Comment: Does anyone know a workaround for handling windows while they are running?  I tried to activate it but I think since it's trying to finish executing that initial macro, the computer won't let any edits to be made to the login screen. I can manually input the info just not working in the code.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about Python, but .... it looks to me like you are trying to do something with the workbook you opened in the Excel Application **after** you have quit the Excel Application.